# Using a Function returning apointer as LValue

Tags: function, pointers, lvalue

Why cant I used a function returning a pointer as a lvalue?

For example this one works

```
int* function()
{
    int* x;
    return x;
}

int main()
{
    int* x = function();
    x = new int(9);
}
```

but not this

```
int* function()
{
    int* x;
    return x;
}

int main()
{
   int* x;
   function() = x;
}
```

1. While I can use a pointer variable as a lvalue, why can't I use a function returning a pointer as a lvalue?
2. Also, when the function returns a
   refernce, instead of a pointer, then
   it becomes a valid lvalue.

Comment: Have you tried putting parentheses around it? e.g. `*(myfunction()) = x;`... also, are you trying to assign to it, or to the location *pointed to* by it (i.e. `x = somepointer;`, or `*x = somepointer;`)? There's a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first sample doesn't do why I think you think it does.  You first store the result of the function call in the variable x and then you override x's value with the newly created array.   *(function()) = 5 should properly try to write 5 to some random memory location specified by the local variable x inside your function.

Sample:

```
int x;

int* function()
{
    return &x;
}

int main()
{
   *(function()) = 5;
   printf("%d\n", x);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please recheck the last statement of main() in second code snippet. Lvalues are variables that can be used to the *left* of the assignment operator (=). You're in effect assigning value x to a function instead of the other way round. 
 A function may take arguments or return values. You cannot directly assign them a value.