# Functions returning pointers to local static/global variables as lvalues in C

Tags: c, lvalue

I was wondering if functions returning pointers to local static/global variables could be used as lvalues in C similarly to C++ so I tried it out and seems like this is possible. Take for example the following simple function,

```
int* d(int a){
    static int* array = NULL;
    static int size = 0;
    if(a+1 > size){
        size = 2*(a+1);
        array = realloc(array, size * sizeof(int));
    }
    if(a == -1){
        free(array);
        return NULL;
    }
    return array + a;
}
```

This is a simple dynamic array, you can do for instance `*d(30) = 2`, but since you can have only one instance of the function per compilation unit, I don't find this very useful.

I thus would like to ask, if there are any interesting uses of this concept in C. Any real applications would be nice too.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I would call this example using a function as lvalue.  You are using the returned pointer as an lvalue.

Comment: It's not the _function_ that is used as an lvalue, it's the value the function _returns_.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/q/2718695/10396 for a similar question

Comment: @JoachimPileborg or rather the integer pointed to by that pointer.

Comment: I understand the function is not the lvalue itself. But I thought it was too long to write "the pointer returned by the function". I thought it would be obvious I'm not referring to the function itself that's why I also provided an example. I'll edit my question to make it clearer.

Comment: -1: You'd get better answers if you'd ask what you want to know instead of something completely different :) EDIT: removed the downvote, as the question was updated.

Answer (score 5):

> I was wondering if functions could be used as lvalues in C like in C++ so I tried it out and seems like this is possible.

No, you're mistaken. Here you're not using the function as an lvalue. You're using the **integer pointed to by the pointer returned by the function** as an lvalue. If you were using the function as an lvalue, that would look like

```
malloc = some_other_function;
```

but in C, this is not possible (you'd get a compiler error). You can, however, create function pointers that can be assigned to:

```
void *(*malloc_wrapper)(size_t);

malloc_wrapper = malloc;

int *arr = malloc_wrapper(10 * sizeof(*arr));
```

Answer (score 0):

This example is dangerous because of the realloc. You can't control what callers do with your pointer. Consider:

```
  *d(0)=0;
   int* insertPoint = d(1); //save for later
   *d(2)=2;  //forces realloc.
   *insertPoint = 1; //CRASH, points to freed memory.
```

I don't think dynamic arrays are a good use case for this technique.

-- edit --

> I was wondering if functions returning pointers to local static/global
>   variables could be used as lvalues...

They could, but as you point out, there can only be one per compilation unit.  So it really becomes an wrapper around a global variable.  Or a method of making a local static act like a global.   So most use cases would just involve using non-standard syntax to perform standard operations.

I have never seen this technique used. The only possible use I could think of it was providing some sort of singleton construct.

Comment: I understand what you're saying. So, are there any good use cases? I tried your example by the way and didn't see any problems with it. Why are you saying "insertPoint" points to freed memory?

Comment: should have said 'may point to freed memory'.  realloc may return the same pointer as the original, if it can extend the block, but it may also return a new block in a totally different area, in which case `insertPoint` is left holding a freed pointer.

Comment: It's not certain to crash, but neither is it safe.  You'd be more likely to encounter trouble if this was part of a larger system doing more `mallocs`, and if the indexes were larger.   And writing to freed memory does not automatically crash, but it usually causes problems on a later `free` or `malloc`.

Comment: Anyway, as much as I appreciate you pointing out possible problems in the code I posted just as an example, you are not answering the question in any way so I cannot mark your answer as the right one.